# awk print an extra line in output with {print $x}

Tags: bash, awk

I searched in the answer with no succes... On RHEL Linux, A first command lists this (I put exactly what I get for those how want to test...):

```
ps -eaf | grep lsnr | grep -v ' LISTENER ' | grep -v grep
oracle   10258     1  0  2014 ?        01:34:43 /logicielPR1/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/bin/tnslsnr PRXPLO -inherit
oracle   10442     1  0  2014 ?        00:24:30 /logicielTE1/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/bin/tnslsnr TECHIMIO -inherit
oracle   10473     1  0  2014 ?        00:28:50 /logicielTE1/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/bin/tnslsnr TEIAC -inherit
oracle   10566     1  0  2014 ?        00:24:50 /logicielTE1/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/bin/tnslsnr TEIMG -inherit
oracle   14192     1  0  2014 ?        00:22:09 /logicielPR1/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/bin/tnslsnr PROCTM2 -inherit
oracle   27167     1  0  2014 ?        00:19:26 /logicielTE1/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/bin/tnslsnr TEOCTM -inherit
oracle   36854     1  0  2014 ?        00:19:59 /logicielTE1/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/bin/tnslsnr TEANA -inherit
oracle   37235     1  0 May20 ?        00:08:32 /logicielPR1/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/bin/tnslsnr PRCHIMIO -inherit
oracle   45141     1  0 Jun03 ?        00:08:02 /logicielST1/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/bin/tnslsnr PRIACS -inherit
oracle   48241     1  0 Sep25 ?        00:04:39 /logicielPR1/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/bin/tnslsnr PRINL -inherit
oracle   48708     1  0 Sep25 ?        00:03:27 /logicielTE1/oracle/product/11.2.0.4/bin/tnslsnr TEINL2 -inherit
```

I want to extract the UPPER name (eg:PRXPLO on the first line), so I do:

```
ps -eaf | grep lsnr | grep -v ' LISTENER ' | grep -v grep | awk -F "${ORA_LISTENER_HEADER}|${ORA_LISTENER_HEADER_UPPER}|tnslsnr " '{print $2}'
PRXPLO -inherit
TECHIMIO -inherit
TEIAC -inherit
TEIMG -inherit
PROCTM2 -inherit
TEOCTM -inherit
TEANA -inherit
PRCHIMIO -inherit
PRIACS -inherit
 {print $2}
PRINL -inherit
TEINL2 -inherit
```

*Note: In this command, "${ORA_LISTENER_HEADER}|${ORA_LISTENER_HEADER_UPPER}|tnslsnr " will be equivalent to "tnslsnr "

Obviously, the line containing " {print $2} " should not exists, but I can not find where it comes from.
I know that I could simply exclude it via a grep, but I would prefer to understand what I do wrong.

Can someone help me on this issue?

Thanks all.

Comment: `ps -cargs= $(pgrep tnslsnr) | awk '$2 != "LISTENER"{print $2}'` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To ease matters, just use one awk call:

```
ps -eaf | awk '/lsnr/ && !/ LISTENER / {print $(NF-1)}'
```

Comment: Very clever... Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you have to exclude it via grep. *awk* is a separate process and it is shown in the list of processes you grep by running the whole chain.

```
ps -eaf | grep lsnr | grep -v ' LISTENER ' | grep -v grep | grep -v awk | awk -F "${ORA_LISTENER_HEADER}|${ORA_LISTENER_HEADER_UPPER}|tnslsnr " '{print $2}'
```

Comment: But in same script, this line:    

      ps -eaf | grep pmon |grep -v grep | awk -F_ '{print $3}'

do not have this problem... Why?
Sorry, I am not script expert...

Comment: The awk command contains the word "lsnr" which you are grepping for. Thus the ps line containing the awk command will be included in the input to the awk command'

Comment: OK, this is a misunderstanding from me. Interesting thing is that none of my coworkers thought about it.